# Passing a bool in c#

Tags: c#, discord, boolean, bots

hey i'm making a discord bot and im trying to set it so that with a command a bool can be set to true / false (it will initiate a different response futher on) but when i do it, it stays as false despite it being set to true. im fairly sure its due to not passing the variable through. how would i go about doing it in this instance?
the bool is called (opse)

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    
    

    public class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        bool opse; 
        [Command("opsset")]
        public async Task trueset(string op)
        {
            
            if (op == "true")
            {
                opse = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Operations is set to active! Set by " + 
                Context.Message.Author.Username);
            }
            if (op == "false")
            {
                opse = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Operations is set to inactive! Set by " + 
                Context.Message.Author.Username);
            }


        }
        [Command("operations")]
        public async Task ops()
        {
             if (opse = true)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Operations are not currently active. Check your 
                designated schedule to see when operations are active");
            }
            if (opse = false)
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Operations are currently active. Message you SO 
                or file an absent report");
            }
        }


       
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single `=` to check for the value of `opse`, which is incorrect. A single `=` is used to assign new values.

To compare values you should use `==`:

```
if (opse == true)
{
  ...
}
if (opse == false)
{
  ...
}
```